# Slow 4K read/write speed

Tags: megaraid, lenovo, readwrite

I've a problem of random writing speed on a Lenovo X3650 M5 with ServeRAID M5210.

The server has seven 600GB SAS disks divided into two logical groups: a RAID1 (2 disks) and a RAID10 (4 disks)

The last disk is a global hot spare.

The RAID 10 has 500MB/s in seq. reads and 250 MB/s in seq. writes and it almost double the speed of the RAID 1 array as expected.

The problems rise during 4K write test with a result of less then 1 MB/S for both RAIDs in both writes and reads.

The logical virtual disks properties:

```
RAID 1:
Write Policy: Write Through
Read Policy: Always Read Ahead
IO Policy: Direct IO
Disk Cache Policy: Unchanged
Background Initialization: Enabled

RAID 10:
Write Policy: Write Through
Read Policy: Always Read Ahead
IO Policy: Direct IO
Disk Cache Policy: Disabled
Background Initialization: Enabled

The Server Profile:
SERVER---
    Server IP:               xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    Server Name:             XXX
    OS name:                 Windows Server 2012
    OS Version:              6.2
    OS Architecture:         x86_64
    Driver Name:             megasas2.sys
    Driver Version:          6.706.06.00
    Application Version:     MegaRAID Storage Manager - 15.03.01.00

HARDWARE---              
    Controller:              Controller0: ServeRAID M5210(Bus 21,Dev 0,Domain 0)
    Status:                  Optimal
    Firmware Package Version:24.7.0-0052
    Firmware Version:        4.270.00-4288
    BBU:                     NO
    Enclosure(s):            1
    Drive(s):                7
    Virtual Drive(s):        2

Enclosures---
    PRODUCT NAME             TYPE                     STATUS                   
    Backplane                Sgpio                    OK                       

Drives---
    CONNECTOR                PRODUCT ID               VENDOR ID                STATE                    DISK TYPE                CAPACITY                 POWER STATE              
    Port 4 - 7               AL13SEB600               LENOVO-X                 Online                   SAS                      557.861 GB               On                                                
    Port 4 - 7               AL13SEB600               LENOVO-X                 Online                   SAS                      557.861 GB               On                                                
    Port 4 - 7               AL13SEB600               LENOVO-X                 Online                   SAS                      557.861 GB               On                                                
    Port 4 - 7               AL13SEB600               LENOVO-X                 Online                   SAS                      557.861 GB               On                                                
    Port 0 - 3               AL13SEB600               LENOVO-X                 Online                   SAS                      557.861 GB               On                                                
    Port 0 - 3               AL13SEB600               LENOVO-X                 Online                   SAS                      557.861 GB               On                                                
    Port 0 - 3               AL13SEB600               LENOVO-X                 Global Hot Spare         SAS                      557.861 GB               On                                                

Virtual Drive(s):---
    TARGET ID                NAME                     CAPACITY                 STATE                    RAID LEVEL               MegaRAID RECOVERY        
    0                        -                        557.861 GB               Optimal                  RAID  1                  NO                                                
    3                        VD_1                     1.090 TB                 Optimal                  RAID  10                 NO
```

Anyone has any advice?

Comment: You haven't posted any benchmark methods and results, but that doesn't sound out of the ordinary for 4K speeds on HDD's.

Comment: Really they are RAIDed SASes not laptop 5,400RPM drives? Though to be fair these SASes could simply be regular 7,200RPM drives but even then not even hitting 1MB/s seems awfully low.

Comment: I just got a reply from LENOVO forum. It seems that the "Write Through" policy that is set in the RAID configuration, can slow down the writing speed. I'll give a try changing the policy and let you know...

Comment: Any update on this, im running into the exact same issue, i dont understand why my results are so much slower then others with the same set up using 10k SAS drives. my 4k tests are also around 1.

Comment: Hi Mar, no updates for now. I'm going to move the production's services to another server in the next weeks and than try to solve the issue.
I'll be back here for any update.